# Entity Framework multi user apps

Tags: entity-framework-6

so I'm willing to develop multi user app using Entity Framework. But I'm not sure how EF exactly handles multiple requests from various users at the same time.

For example: user1 is inserting a record into some table. What happens when user2 inserts a record at that table at the same moment?

Comment: When two people insert a record simultaneously... two records are inserted. When two people update the same record.... whoever was last overwrites whoever was first. Nothing earth shattering. There's only a problem if you want to do stuff like make sure they have a unique key. If you tell us what database, and what you are really worried about we might be able to help.

Comment: To handle those scenarios is the job of the **underlying database system** - EF is really not involved much in this. It just talks to the database server and handles any errors reported back. This will be exactly the same as if you're using "raw ADO.NET" with straight up SQL queries - no difference

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with multiple-users at all, this is a concurrency question (because the same user could issue multiple commands simultaneously too).

Database servers (like SQL Server) [have a variety of ways to deal with concurrency](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189132(v=sql.105).aspx) (such as table and row locking, and transaction locks), and [Entity Framework adds its own concurrency features](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) like Optimistic and Pessimistic Concurrency.

You'll need to research those topics yourself, it will explain how concurrency is handled.